# How can I use mod_rewrite to redirect to a "key word" folder

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

It is hard to explain in title.

I want to make the following two URLs

> http://www.example.com/apps/web/admin/**images**/pic.jpg
>   http://www.example.com/apps/web/blog/comment/**images**/pic.jpg

both redirect to

> http://www.example.com/apps/view/**images**/pic.jpg

I put the ".htaccess" file in /apps/ folder.

No matter what is the current URL,
as long as the current URL contain the "images/",
all redirect to this folder

> http://www.example.com/apps/view/**images**

this is my code but it cannot work

> RewriteEngine On
>
> RewriteRule ^(.*)/images/(.*)$ views/images/$2

so, how can I set the .htaccess file?

Comment: I'm sorry, I forgot to paste my code,
and I will add my code to the question.

Comment: and I was just getting on learning the skills of the mod_rewrite.
Please excuse me

Comment: No worries, your edits are just fine :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /apps/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/view/images/
RewriteRule images/(.*)$ view/images/$1 [L]
```

If you actually want to redirect the browser, as in changing the URL in the address bar, change the `L` in the brackets to `L,R=301`

Comment: But now I have another question....
Because sometimes I cannot use Server to work, so the root is not http://www.example.com/, maybe likes http://localhost/~user/example/apps.
So, how can I adjust it to make it work?
If I remove "RewriteBase /apps/", it will show me "Internal Server Error"

Comment: @AzureChen change the base to `~user/example/apps` and place the rules in that directory.

Comment: I have tried in my local computer, but if I used "RewriteBase /~user/example/public_html/apps/" it still show me "Internal Server Error".
If I used "RewriteBase /apps/" it will show me 
"The requested URL  /apps/view/images/pic.jpg was not found" :(

Comment: Thank you! you really have patience!
And I want to know why it will show "Internal Server Error" when I didn't set RewriteCond?

Comment: @azurechen because the rules loop, the rewrite engine keeps repeating until the URI stops changing